# How to check the radio button in a table column, using row id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an html table with two columns- text and pair radio button; I have set the id of the rows.I want to dynamically check a radio button using the id of the row. 
HTML:

```
<tr class="tbrder" id="area1">
    <td class="biglable">Leadership University</td>
    <td class="smalllable">
        <div class="switch pull-right">
            <input type="radio" class="radio" value="y">Y
            <input type="radio" class="radio" value="n">N
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

If I receive ID area1 from the backend, i want to set the radio button to Y

Comment: And your JavaScript/jQuery code is?

Comment: @DivyeshSavaliya what backend has to do here??

Comment: May be `$('.tbrder [class="radio"]').on('change', function(){ ... })`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can access to this td 
by use this code
I don't know if there's another way better than this
it's not ideal method 
but it works

```
 var myRow = document.getElementById("area1");
 var myColumn = myRow.children.item(1);
 var myRadioButtons = myColumn .getElementsByClassName("radio");
 myRadioButtons[0].checked = true; //
```

then you can change it's value

Comment: Thanks mate. Helped a lot

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you have a `php` page as backend

```
$.ajax({
    url:'YOUR_PHP_PAGE.php',
    ....,
    ....,
    success:function(data){
        if(data=='area1')
        {
            $(":radio[value='y']").prop("checked",true);
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also use this code.

```
$('#area1').find(':radio[value="y"]').prop("checked",true);
```